# Node.js TLS " TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

I use nodejs 5.9.0 and express. In my code, I create the server this way:

```
var app = express();

var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};
tls.createServer(options, app).listen(3000);

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

HTTP works fine. But when I tried to access https://localhost:3000, it throws below exception:

```
C:\src\nodejs\videos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:140
  var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.handle (C:\src\nodejs\videos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:140:27)
    at EventEmitter.handle (C:\src\nodejs\videos\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:173:10)
    at Server.app (C:\src\nodejs\videos\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:38:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:817:14)
    at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:593:8)
    at TLSSocket.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:65:8)
 Program node bin/www exited with code 1
```

Did I use nodejs TLS and express the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `https`, not `tls`, with Express apps since `tls` is basically just a plain TCP connection (secured by TLS):

```
var app = express();

var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000);
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting... that was basically the code I used initially, but the browser threw me security exceptions. Well... I did upgrade my nodejs from 5.5.0 to 5.9.0 in last 30 minutes. Not sure whether that fixed the issue.